# How to pass on credentials to another website?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET intranet website that needs to communicate with another website that uses the logged in user's active directory credentials.

I know I am probably not explaining this very well.. But, here is a real life example of what I am trying to fix:

User opens browser, navigates to my intranet site and is logged in automatically based on active directory credentials. Within my site, I have a link to open up  the webpage in question within my 'default.aspx' page. This request is denied due to invalid credentials since it is looking at my website's application user's credentials.

User can open up the page in question in another window, since it uses the right active directory credentials.

How do I pass currently logged in user's credentials to website in question through my website? Sorry, this may be a bit confusing.

Update: Site is on the same domain, not the same server. I believe it is also .NET

Comment: It sounds like you are just looking for basic Single Sign On, yeah?  Some details you may want to include in your question:  Is the second site also .NET?  Is it on the same server?  Within the same domain?  Short answer: You'll need to pass a token to the second website which identified the user, and lets the second site know that this user is logged in on the first site. And that website will need to examine the token to see if it's valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question with the details. Thank you also for suggesting SSO. I didn't know how to Google my way out of this, and you provided me with a good starting place.

Comment: Sounds good!  SSO is too varied to be able to give you detailed instructions.  But hopefully having a name for what you want to do will help.  Since you didn't say "Single Sign On" I had a hunch you just didn't know what to call what you were trying to do, and knowing the name for it would be a big help.